# Keep value at top of drop down list after selection

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu, listbox

I have a listbox that is getting data from my database, it contains names of continents. I have a dropdown list that populates with countries depending on the name of the continent that was chosen in the list. I want the drop down list to have "Select a country" as the default first value after a choice has been made but it doesn't work.

this is my approach at doing it

```
protected void lbCont_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListItem liSelectCount = new ListItem("Select a country...", "-1");
            ddlCount.Items.Insert(0, liSelectCount);
        }
```

Comment: Please be specific about how it doesn't work. What *exactly* happens when your function here is called?

Comment: Why not just hide the country dropdown until a continent is chosen? I'm no UX master, but this seems like a strange approach to this.

Comment: When I select a value in the listbox, the dropdown list IS populated with the countries that I want it to be populated with, but the "Select a country..." does not show.

Comment: [Try this solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/403a897a-03e0-41dd-b837-6c965f46ff7d/how-to-set-default-value-for-dropdownlist-connected-to-datasource?forum=csharpgeneral)

Answer (score 1):

Is this an ASP .NET project?  If so, your code looks correct to me.

It's possible the issue is that your `lbCont_SelectedIndexChanged` event isn't firing.  You can test this by setting a breakpoint on that event method and testing to see what happens.  If it doesn't fire, you can fix it by setting the `AutoPostBack` property on your listbox control to True.

Here's a small working example for you which selectively binds a couple of different datasources to a dropdown list and then copies the code you're using above to insert "Select a country..." as the first item in the dropdown list.

**Default.aspx code:**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h2>Dropdown List Test</h2>
        </div>
        <div>

            Continent Listbox: 
            <p>
                <asp:ListBox ID="lbCont" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lbCont_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">Continent 1</asp:ListItem>

                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Continent 2</asp:ListItem>

                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Continent 3</asp:ListItem>

                </asp:ListBox>
            </p>

            Countries Dropdown: 
            <p>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCount" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </p>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Default.aspx.cs code:**

```
protected void lbCont_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    switch (lbCont.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            dt.TableName = "CountriesTable1";
            dt.Columns.Add("CountryID");
            dt.Columns.Add("CountryName");
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "Country 1a");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Country 1b");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Country 1c");
            break;

        case 1:
            dt.TableName = "CountriesTable2";
            dt.Columns.Add("CountryID");
            dt.Columns.Add("CountryName");
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "Country 2a");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Country 2b");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Country 2c");
            break;

        case 2:
            dt.TableName = "CountriesTable3";
            dt.Columns.Add("CountryID");
            dt.Columns.Add("CountryName");
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "Country 3a");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Country 3b");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Country 3c");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    ddlCount.DataSource = dt;
    ddlCount.DataTextField = "CountryName";
    ddlCount.DataValueField = "CountryID";
    ddlCount.DataBind();

    // Same as yours
    ListItem liSelectCount = new ListItem("Select a country...", "-1");
    ddlCount.Items.Insert(0, liSelectCount);
}
```

So using this code, your approach of adding "Select a country" works well.  You just need to make sure `AutoPostBack` is set to True on the listbox control otherwise the `lbCont_SelectedIndexChanged` event won't fire.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call the `DataBind()` method on your DDL after inserting into it...
I'm concerned though, that you have the possibility of inserting that option over-and-over again, if they change the continent multiple times.  You should probably check to see if it's there prior to inserting it.

Comment: This didn't help me. Sorry.